# Autocompletion Background Colour in ble.sh

Tags: bash

I've decided to switch back to *Bash* from *Fish*, but I can't live anymore without syntax highlighting, so I've installed [*ble.sh*](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh) to do the same in *Bash*. Everything is fine, except that I can't find any information about setting background colour of autocompletions — it's always blinding white:

[image: screenshot]

In [this section](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh#highlight-colors) author describes how to set highlighiting colours, but none of this applies to autocompletions colours.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the face `auto_complete` to configure the style of suggestions by auto-complete.

Here are some examples for the setting in your `~/.blerc`:

```bash
# blerc

# ble-0.4+ (edit: 2022-12-04, fix 2023-02-10)
ble-face auto_complete='fg=242,bg=235'
ble-face auto_complete='fg=white,bg=69'
ble-face auto_complete='fg=240,underline,italic'

# ble-0.3
ble-color-setface auto_complete fg=242,bg=235
ble-color-setface auto_complete fg=white,bg=69
ble-color-setface auto_complete fg=240,underline,italic
```

I'm sorry for inconvenience. I updated `README.md` in [the latest commit 50327c3](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh/commit/50327c392b386f8de3feea838111a8341bb80d08). I also changed `ble-color-setface` [edit: renamed to `ble-face` in ble-0.4] to output the settings of current faces when no argument is supplied. Now, with the latest devel version, you can check the list of faces by the following command:

```bash
$ ble-color-setface
ble-color-setface auto_complete fg=246,underline,italic
ble-color-setface blerc_git_commit_id fg=navy
(snip)
ble-color-setface vbell_erase bg=252
ble-color-setface vbell_flash fg=green,reverse
```

Comment: How can I disable exit status outputs like `[ble: exit ...]`?

Comment: For the current devel version, please put an empty function `TRAPERR() { :; }` in your `~/.blerc`. Outputting exit status is the default behavior when `TRAPERR` is not defined.

Comment: @undefined I newly implemented an option `exec_errexit_mark`. When you use the latest version, please add `bleopt exec_errexit_mark=''` in `blerc` to disable exit status mark.

Comment: I put up a feature request for more muted or black and white colors, maybe like Gruvbox, or just more like Fish Autosuggest here: https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh/issues/258

Comment: I have to use **ble-face auto_complete=fg=242,bg=235"**, with an extra **"="** after the **auto_complete** keyword

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/821163/1620059 , show all the colors, i.e. **`curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/HaleTom/89ffe32783f89f403bba96bd7bcd1263/raw/e50a28ec54188d2413518788de6c6367ffcea4f7/print256colours.sh | bash`**,  @akinomyoga, how about putting it into ble.sh?

Comment: Ah, right. The equal sign was missing. Or the option `-f` was missing. I have updated the answer. Thank you! @caoanan

Comment: @caoanan
> *show all the colors,* ... ble.sh already has `ble palette` for that.

Comment: @akinomyoga ah, great! thank you.

Comment: I updated the layout of the color table of `ble palette` in commit [`bb8541da`](https://github.com/akinomyoga/ble.sh/commit/bb8541da3e7eb5cebfe87541eb0873b3a32b759b)

Comment: @akinomyoga how do I differentiate the autocomplete highlighting from the highlighting when I'm cycling through the options? I find it very difficult to read when it's blue over a gray background

Comment: @Alex Braga Sorry for the delayed answer. I'm not always watching StackOverflow, etc. If you want a quick response, please report it on a GitHub Issue or Discussion. The autocomplete highlighting and menu item highlighting are controlled by different faces, `auto_complete` and `region_insert`, respectively. The *blue* color depends on the terminal's color theme, so the characters can be illegible depending on your terminal setting. To change the highlighting color of the temporarily inserted menu items, you can change the face `region_insert`.